# gapfill in Rssa give me error

Tags: r

I am trying to gapfill a simple data using Rssa library in R:

```
library(Rssa)
dt=EuStockMarkets
fame=data.frame(dt)
fame$DAX[150:200]=NA
fame$SMI[150:200]=NA
fame$CAC[150:200]=NA
fame$FTSE[150:200]=NA
s <- ssa(fame, kind = "mssa")
g <- gapfill(s, groups = list(1:6))
#NO error here

plot(g)

fame=fame[1:200,]
View(fame)
s <- ssa(fame, kind = "mssa")
g <- gapfill(s, groups = list(1:6))
```

I am using EuStockMarkets dataset. However, when I restrict data to 1 to 200, it gives this error

> "    Error in gapfill.mssa(s, groups = list(1:6)) : 
>         gapfilling should start from shaped SSA object"

**EDIT**: When I use `fame = fame[1:202,]`, it doesn't give such error..but I kinda need to do a prediction so the tail of data should be set to NA.

Comment: When you take `fame[1:200,]` you will see that the series length of `s` will be *149*, although it should be 200. Maybe if the last rows are NA, its not a `gap` anymore.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `forecast` family of functions (e.g. `rforecast` / `vforecast`) to perform gap-filling from the end of the series (also known as "series forecasting"). You could also use `bforecast` to construct bootstrap confidence bounds for the forecast.

Note that MSSA case is a bit special, since there the series could be of different lengths and therefore NA's could be used to pad the series as necessary (e.g. if you represent them as matrix / data.frame – exactly your case).

See Ch 2. and 3. in https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i02 for some additional comments of forecasting specifics in MSSA case.